# php asort not working for text string array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, text

I have an array

```
print_r($RL_all_years_unique_0);
```

Gives:

```
Array ( [0] => kWh Electricity [1] => Kg Refrigerants [2] => Gallons Diesel [3] => Indirect VMT [4] => Short Tons Solid Waste [5] => Gallons Propane [6] => Cubic Ft Nat Gas [7] => Gallons 87 Gasoline [8] => WasteWater - kg N [9] => WasteWater - Pop )
```

I then do:

```
asort($RL_all_years_unique_0);
print_r($RL_all_years_unique_0);
```

Gives:

```
Array ( [6] => Cubic Ft Nat Gas [7] => Gallons 87 Gasoline [2] => Gallons Diesel [5] => Gallons Propane [3] => Indirect VMT [1] => Kg Refrigerants [4] => Short Tons Solid Waste [9] => WasteWater - Pop [8] => WasteWater - kg N [0] => kWh Electricity )
```

Why is kWh Electricity at the end, instead of after `"Kg Refrigerants"`? Everything is alphabetical except that.

Comment: do any of the sort flags make a difference?

Comment: It's because the lower is > upper char

Comment: so http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php is the answer

Comment: natcasesort fixed it thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) for case insensitive sort.

```
natcasesort($RL_all_years_unique_0);
print_r($RL_all_years_unique_0);
```

or

```
sort($fruits, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

or

```
asort($fruits, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```